# Google App Engine Bulkloader appcfg.py download_data vs. Datastore Backup Entities Button

Tags: python, google-app-engine, backup, database-backups, bulkloader

I am currently looking for the best way to backup my Google App Engine's webapp datastore. From the reading I have been doing it seems like there are two different ways I can do this. I can either use the GAE's bulkloader by calling appcfg.py upload_data --application= --kind= --filename=  OR I can go into my webapp's datastore admin section, select the entities I want to backup, and then click the "Backup Entities" button. Unless I am mistaken, the "Backup Entities" button will create a backup of my datastore in the blobstore while using the appcfg.py's download_data will create a local backup. The backups will be happening weekly/monthly and the primary reason will be in case one of the webapp's admins accidently deletes important data. I am not worried about Google losing data, so that should not be taken into consideration when reviewing my question.

So my question is: which of these two methods is the preferred method? Which of them is faster, more efficient, cheaper, etc.?

Thanks in advance for your comments/help/answers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here are some factors to consider along with the solution that I think handles it best:

**Dev Time** - *Datastore Admin* - 
To leverage Bulkloader, you'll need to write scripts, maintain backup servers, storage, etc.

**Cost** - *Datastore Admin* - 
YMMV but our backup of tens of millions of entities used <1% of the 1bil Task Queue quota.  The cost for datastore read operations and storage will be specific to your application.  But between the two options, the read operations should be the same and you're trading Outgoing Bandwidth ($0.12/GB) in Bulkloader for Blobstore storage ($0.0043/GB) with Datastore Admin.

**Backup Duration** - *Datastore Admin* - 
As you would expect, mapreduce shards writing data to Blobstore inside Google's network is much much faster than streaming the entity data out one at a time.  A full backup of our data with Datastore Admin takes under 6 hours.  With Bulkloader it takes over 3 days.

**Backup Maintenance** - *Bulkloader (for now)* - 
With Bulkloader and a server, you can create crons to regularly perform backups and backup maintenance.  For example, we have a server in Rackspace that backs up our datastore every 3 days and keeps the last 2 backups.  With Datastore Admin you have to manually perform the backup and delete stale backups, until an automated solution is published ([Issue 7040](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=7040)).  Even still, for once a month backups, the cost of doing it manually with Datastore Admin is so low that I'd recommend it.

**Data Flexibility** - *Bulkloader* - 
With bulkloader you can export all your data into human-readable csv files allowing you to pivot it in Excel, create a test dataset for your local development environment, or even move your operation to another app hosting service (ex: AWS) should you require it.

**Precision Restore** - *Bulkloader* - 
Bulkloader can handle restoring select entities (where you know exactly which entities you deleted or overwrote) and bulk restores.  Datastore Admin can only do bulk restore for all the entities of a given Kind.

**Bulk Restore** - *Datastore Admin* - 
Datastore Admin minimizes very expensive writes by only updating changed entities.  Sharding also makes this process much, much faster than a simple Bulkloader upload (though you could shard the csv backup data across many clients yourself).

Ultimately Bulkloader gives you more precise control while Datastore Admin simplifies and speeds up bulk backup/restore.  Even though Datastore Admin is new and has a few issues ([7076](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=7076)), given your situation, I'd definitely recommend it.

Comment: Awesome answer. Sorry for the delay in the upvote. Much appreciated!

Comment: no one's mentioned here yet but the docs make it sound like bulkloader only works on the now-deprecated Master/Slave datastore? https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadingdata#Downloading_and_Uploading_All_Data  ...or does that apply only to the `download_data` command and not bulkloaders?

Comment: The download_data command for appcfg.py definitely works on High Replication datastores, and that's what bulkloader uses to get data from the datastore into a CSV file.  I haven't seen the high_replication_warning but it's quite possible you'll miss recently added entities and have broken references in your data.

Comment: It seems that cron-triggered backups are now supported in Datastore Admin https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/scheduled_backups

Answer (score 4):

It's really a decision between running the download operation locally, entity-by-entity, or doing the export in the cloud using Map/Reduce and downloading the compiled package of everything.

There's probably less chance of failure or corruption if you use the datastore admin utility - personally, I've always had problems downloading complex schemas using appcfg, and I've stuck to datastore admin since.

**In terms of speed** - datastore admin can definitely outscale and outperform your local computer, depending on how you set up the task queue that executes your datastore admin job ([using task queue rate control](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/queue.html#Defining_Push_Queues_and_Processing_Rates) or by [sending tasks to a dedicated backend via the `target` parameter](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/queue.html#target)).

**In terms of cost** - Map/Reduce can get expensive really fast - in places you may not expect. In one job that required deleting 144,000 entities, there ended up being almost 11.54 million (!!) datastore write calls. `appcfg`'s bulk downloader doesn't touch your write quota or your task queue quotas.

**In terms of efficiency** - It's probably much quicker for an AppEngine instance to download an entity from the datastore and put it in the Blobstore than your local machine downloading it directly. Map/Reduce in general is also very efficient, especially on AppEngine.

The answer to your question depends on the size of your dataset, your budget, and how much patience you have. Map/Reduce (via datastore admin) will be more consistent and faster, but could cost a lot more depending on your setup.

Comment: see "AppEngine Bulkloader is not downloading list properties" for an example issue with complex schemas: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4327882/appengine-bulk-downloader-is-not-downloading-list-properties

Comment: Yeah I also reported the list properties as a bug to App Engine and had it acknowledged. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9089060/attributeerror-list-object-has-no-attribut-has-key-in-app-engine